# How can we implement Face and fingerprint in IONIC 5/Angular with Cordova which works both in IOS and Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

I implemented Biometric with Fingerprint AIO, It works fine for Fingerprint but Face auth is not working, it gives an error while Authenticating message when I try to login using face, Any solution will be helpful.

I am using Ionic 5  with Angular 8,
Fingerprint AIO- 5.0.0
Below is the code i am using

```
    return this.fingerPrintAIO.show({
          clientId: 'Fingerprint-Demo',
          clientSecret: 'password', 
          disableBackup: false,
          localizedFallbackTitle: 'Use Pin',
          localizedReason: 'Please authenticate'
        });
async isFingerprintAvailable() {
    let result = false;
    const promise = await this.fingerPrintAIO.isAvailable();
    promise.then((response) => {
      if (response === "finger" || response === "face") {
      this.presentFingerPrint().then((resp: any) =>{
            console.log('Inside success');
         }).catch(e => {
               console.log('Inside failure on cancel');
            });
       }
      result = true;
      console.log('fingerprint available : ', response);
    });
    promise.catch((error) => {
      result = false;
      console.log('fingerprint error : ', error);
    });
    return result;
  }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please share some more information. What is the error?

Comment: @tomerpacific Please check the code above, We are getting couldn't recognize it, We are able to log in for other apps which are in Playstore